# How to write a function's result use function spit?

Tags: clojure

I have this code:

```
(defn a[]
  1
  )

(defn test []
  (spit "test.txt" a))
```

when run test,the test.txt only have the object's name:

```
test$a@603494de
```

but I want it have the value 1

or if I use with-open:

```
(defn test1 []
  (with-open [w (clojure.java.io/writer "test.txt")]
    (.write w a)))
```

got error:IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: write for class java.io.BufferedWriter

but if I write:

```
(.write w "a")
```

there is no error

how to fix it?Thanks!

Comment: a is a function, the object's name is the printed representation of the function object. You should call it to obtain 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening:

First, `a` is a function. You need to either call it and get the value, or use `def` instead (since its constant):

```
(def a 1) ;; no need to call a
(defn a[] 1) ;; need to call a: (a)
```

Second, (assuming you kept `defn` and `a` is still a function), to create a string as an argument for `spit` you need to use `str`:

```
(spit "test.txt" (str (a))) ;; note a is called
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked.and I want to know if the function is this:(defn a [thevec] (filter (fn [x] (not= x nil)) thevec))  I try to use it like this: (spit "text.txt" (str (apply a (list [nil 1])))) but the test.txt only have this: clojure.lang.LazySeq@20

Comment: @wangkai Your `a` returns a lazy seq and the `.toString()` is what gets printed. Without knowing `a`, maybe `(str (into [] (apply ...)))` helps.  But unless you need this for debugging this all looks a bit wonky.